# How to compare if source list does not contain any object which is present in destination list using Java 8?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

```
List<EPosition> has S and P role.
```

For some employee, P role exists but now S does not exists.

So Source will only provide P but not S row in list.

In Database, WE have both P as well as S. 
We want to make all S row as NULL (do not delete). So how to compare two lists

```
 List<EPosition> src; //Fetch from Soap
 List<EPosition> db;//Fetch from DB

 for (EPosition d: db){
   for (Eposition s: src){
     if (s.ID = d.ID){
           //Make it null
     }
   }
 }
 merge later
```

Comment: When you want to modify rows in a database, you should use a database operation.

Answer (score 4):

**Problem statement:** From the problem statement, what I understood is you have two lists (say A and B), where A contains some objects which are also present in B and you want to set this value to null in A using java streams.
**Solution:** So to do that you need to use the map on stream where each object is mapped to null if you find the object in B  else object itself. To find whether the object is present in B there are two ways :
a. use contains method of the list (this will use equals method of the object in your case Eposition)

```
   dbs = dbs.stream()
           .map(db -> return src.contains(db) ? null :db)
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

b. simply iterate over second list using stream and find a match of the id using anyMatch function.

```
   dbs = dbs.stream()
           .map(db -> return src.stream().anyMatch(sid -> sid.ID.equals(did.ID) ? null :db)
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: While this code might answer the question, can you consider adding some explanation for what the problem was you solved, and how you solved it? This will help future readers to understand your answer better and learn from it.

Comment: I would remove the nulls with a filter(Objects::notNull) before collecting.